# setting one array for X axis (in time, each day) and for series only set Y points

Tags: highcharts

How can I set only one time X axis points array in utc datetime.
(even better if there is `startPoint:dateFrom` and `endPoint:DateEnd` for for each day)

Then in series I put only Y points for each my charttype ?

is this possible ? Because actually my series object have this data :

```
let data = [{
            "name": "< 100 MB",
            "type": "column",
            "data": [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 1), 2],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 2), 3],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 3), 3],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 4), 2],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 5), 1]
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "< 10 MB",
            "type": "column",
            "data": [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 1), 3],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 2), 3],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 3), 2],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 4), 4],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 5), 10]
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "< 1 MB",
            "type": "column",
            "data": [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 1), 2],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 2), 3],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 3), 2],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 4), 3],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 5), 5]
            ]
        }];
```

You can see all my X axis are same... how can improve this ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-pointstart-datetime/

Comment: Thanks a lot this is nearly what I need BUT now If I use dataGrouping by week or by year it wont works http://jsfiddle.net/L7d5d8fj/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646494/datagrouping-with-xaxis-datetime