# dataGrouping with xAxis datetime

Tags: highcharts

I wonder if it's possible with xAxis type datetime set this

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
```

But if I want a dataGrouping option by week dynamically I can't see here: http://jsfiddle.net/L7d5d8fj/

Comment: It is because you have used Highcharts library. dataGrouping is available with highstock.js: http://jsfiddle.net/L7d5d8fj/1/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński thanks but I think this seems not working very good https://jsfiddle.net/ezhp5a4j/2/   (just click on ALL) you will see the red is not  in good position, is there possbiility to draw area depend of each column MAX point

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with line series. Could you please specify this issue?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I need an area  behind my stacked column which follow the maximum point of each column I have an serie type:area with sum of each column but when you click on ALL button you will see my area (red color) is not at good place you can check...

Comment: It is because you have different approximation for your column and for line series. You can manually set your approximation: https://jsfiddle.net/ezhp5a4j/4/ If it will meet your requirement I would like to post it as an answer

Comment: this is solution thanks @GrzegorzBlachliński you are the best :D

Answer (score 0):

dataGrouping will work on Highstock chart only: 
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping

As an answer to your problem with showing lines and columns in your chart (discussion in comments) You can set your approximation manually, so you will be sure that both of your series types have the same approximation:

```
  dataGrouping: {
    approximation: "average",
    enabled: true,
    forced: true,
    units: [
      ['week', [1]]
    ]
  }
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ezhp5a4j/4/